# Reactivate a dormant account with Bank of America as a nonresident

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, non-resident

I am a French Citizen, I opened an account with Bank of America in 2009 that I used every year during my vacations, but I have not been to the US for 5 years so the account seems to be dormant. I would like to reactivate it and recover the money because I will be staying in California for 3 months starting in Sept. I cannot manage to connect to anybody in the branch where I opened the account, all the people I managed to talk to said I had to go to a BoA branch on my arrival to reactivate the account, I would just like to be sure I can recover the money...

Comment: Generally as long as you can validate your identity, you will have access to the account and whatever money is in it. However, keep in mind that sometimes these assets considered "abandoned" or "unclaimed" will be sent to the state at which time you will have to get it from them, but you will find out when you visit them which is the case.

Comment: Contact the mother ship (Bank America).  They have the records and they can tell you the status of the account as well as what you have to do to activate it, close whether you need to contact the state if it was deemed  abandoned. Each state's web site lays out the recovery process for unclaimed money.

Answer (score 1):

In the US if a bank account is closed for inactivity the bank sends the funds to the state government.  Most (all?) state governments have a website to lookup information on these unclaimed accounts.

There should be no charge to get that money back from the state, assuming the state doesn't have a problem sending it to a out of the country address. The website will give a procedure for proving that you are the rightful recipient.

This gets the money back, it doesn't reestablish the account. If the money has been turned over to the state, then getting the account reopened by the bank will most likely result in a account with a 0 dollar balance.